# Can i set same interstitial ads code on two different fragments?

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner, interstitial

Let's say I have an app with two fragments. Fragment A has Button A and fragment B has Button B. I am wondering if I set the same interstitial or banner code to that two different fragments and buttons it is ok or against to google Admob policy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with that. I have been using same IDs in different apps.